# Fatal error when compiling llvm/clang - 'cstddef' file not found

Tags: c++, macos, clang

When trying to compile llvm/clang

```
../llvm/configure --enable-cxx11=yes --enable-libcpp=yes 
  --enable-optimized=yes --prefix=/usr/local --enable-targets=all 
  --with-gcc-toolchain=/usr/local/bin --enable-bindings=auto
```

the following error occurs:

```
[...]llvm/include/llvm/Support/AlignOf.h:19:10: fatal error: 'cstddef' file not found
#include <cstddef>
         ^
1 error generated.
rm: [...]/llvm_build/lib/Support/Release+Asserts/APFloat.d.tmp: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [[...]/llvm_build/lib/Support/Release+Asserts/APFloat.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

But `cstddef` does indeed exist (in `/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.0/`). Adding `--includedir=/usr/local/include/c++/4.8.0/` to the configure does not help also.

What can be the cause for this?

Comment: Two remarks: IMHO the correct option is `-I<path>`, not `--includedir<pat>`. In addition, at least at my OSX machine, `cstddef` is in `/usr/include/c++/...`, not in `/usr/local/include/c++/...`, but YMMV.

Comment: `--includedir`, along with the other options, is what is mentioned in `./configure --help`. `cstddef` is in `/usr/local/...`, because I also have installed the recent GCC to that location.

Comment: Sorry, I thougt the option goes to clang. Have you checked the calling parameters for clang?

Answer (score 10):

```bash
$ sudo apt install libstdc++-12-dev
```

it solves my problem in ubuntu 22.04. See  https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Base-Toolkit/On-upgrading-to-Ubuntu-22-0-4-the-standard-libraries-are-no/td-p/1455303.

You can find different versions of libstdc++ by searching https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_packages, such as [this results page for the amd64 architecture](https://packages.debian.org/search?arch=amd64&keywords=libstdc%2B%2B-+dev).

Answer (score 1):

Try building with `cmake` or re-installing dependancies below

```
mkdir build
cd build/
cmake .. \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86_64;JSBackend" \
-DLLVM_INCLUDE_EXAMPLES=OFF
```

I ran into similar errors and installed the essential `gcc-4.8` and `libstdc++-4.8` libraries. Worked for me atleast.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Good luck. Hope it works